# How to exclude External Libraries in IntelliJ from .jar file

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, build.gradle

I am working on a Kotlin project where we periodically scan our .jar file for licensing issues. A lot of the issues getting picked up are not used directly in my project, but are in the External Libraries section of IntelliJ.

I don't think there is any reason for these external libraries to be part of my .jar file. How do I exclude the entire External Libraries section? Or, how can I exclude certain files in the External Libraries area?

I have tried adding the following to my build.gradle

```
jar {
   sourceSets {
      main {
        kotlin {
           exclude [filepath]
        }
      }
   }
}
```

which seems to work for folders inside my project, but not within the External Libraries file.

Am I able to exclude files or folders in the External Libraries area using sourceSets?

Comment: Don't add any dependency in your build.gradle, and you'll have no external library. Why did you add those dependencies in the first place if you don't need them? I think you actually need them.

Comment: Above comment is correct. You need not to add such dependencies in build.gradle file if you do not need them.